# Immovable Meta tag inside background image style

Tags: php, html

I've run into an interesting problem that I've found no information about. I'm using cPanel's text editor for edits.
I had a header tag for months, unchanged, working perfectly, that looked like this:

```
<header class="cat-header" style="background-image:url('<?= $bgImg ?>')"></header>
```

Suddely, without making any change in the tag, the header images were replaced by the characters ')"
Looking into it I found the following:

```
<header class="cat-header" style="background-image:url('<?= $bgImg ?><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">')"></header>
```

Since I'm not the only one with access to the website's code, I suspected someone else added the `<meta>` tag for optimization purposes, or something else. I moved it outside of the `<header>`, saved the file, checked the website - it works again.
But just as I close the file, the meta tag moves back inside the `<header>`. The thing is unstoppable, changing it has no effect (tried replacing literal quote characters with `&quot;`), copy-pasting it removes the duplicate. Everything else is saved correctly, the only way to remove it is to remove the `<header>` entirely.

Comment: have you tried putting it in the actual head of the document

Comment: For some reason I expected this tag to be already there - it wasn't. It solved the problem, the images now appear correctly. However, the code itself that I see when I open the source files got even more ridiculous: a) The meta tag reappeared inside the header b) I cannot see the copied part in the head tag - which is stored in a different file

Comment: Edit: it is in the `<head>`, just not in the same row where I put it

Comment: sounds like your editor is trying to auto correct your code then